# Numbering subsubsections in Lyx

Tags: lyx

I need to number subsubsections i used in my Lyx document. I have tried to use the unnumbered subsubsection and the numbered default one, but it is does not matter whhich one i select . It is always unnumbered anyway.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can go to "Document > Settings... > Numbering & TOC" and slide those sliders to the position you need. The table below shows the expected result of the sliders.

This may depend on your chosen document class and style. If it still doesn't work, you should provide the class/style/template.